# Encoding/Decoding data in c++ using encoder/decoder logic gate rules

Tags: c++, encoding, compression, bit

Is there a way to deal with bits in c++(c is ok too!) in a way to emulate an encoder(or decoder) logic gate?

For example: encoding a byte(8 bits) into only 3 bits, or a word (16 bits) into 4 bits only and vise versa. exactly in the way encoder and decoder logic gate do it.

The goal of this is data compression (I know that there are better ways, but this is a single phase of the process and it must be done in this way for the project purposes)

**Encoder Logic gate:**

[image: Encoder Logic gate]

**Decoder Logic gate:**

[image: Decoder Logic gate]

**Note:** it can be done with bitwise operators but I need a really really fast and efficient way so that I can do it billions of times peer second!

Comment: Take a look at `std::vector<bool>`, it is a specialized representation of a bitset.

Comment: Well, kind of both yes and no. C++ has bit-wise operations and bit-fields so "yes, that logic can be implemented` but you can't save just 3 bits. You'll always have to use at least 8 bits in memory so you won't really gain anything. So "no, not really".

Comment: @Botje what about the efficiency side? I added a little note to the end of the post, read it, please

Comment: @4386427 Yup  I know, what I meant by  that was using only 3 bits of a byte to store the encoding result,and having the remaining 5 bits to store data from other encoded bytes.

Comment: @MuhammadNihad you are aware that the `Dn` is a one-hot type and that coding/decoding fails if more than one `Dn` is set. ?

Comment: @4386427 Sorry, but what do you mean by Dn?

Comment: Please don't add requirements after the fact. @YvesDaoust 's implementation is 10 instructions. Assuming the case of 1 instruction per cycle, this will yield hundreds of millions of invocations per second on a single core. If you really need to hit that target, you will either need to use multiple cores and eat the coordination/memory overhead, or switch to SIMD and eat extra complexity.

Comment: "do it billions of times peer second" -- based on the knowledge displayed in the question, that's a rather unrealistic goal. Especially if you want to do something practical, i.e. feeding some meaningful data in, and doing something with the results rather than just throwing them away.

Comment: @MuhammadNihad By `Dn` I mean the input bit `D0`, `D1`, `D2` ...

Comment: @DanMašek: simulating a complex ASIC or FPGA would be a legitimate application requiring high performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you pack the bits in bytes,

**Encoder:**

```
Q= 4 * ((D & 0xF0) != 0) + 2 * ((D & 0x66) != 0) + ((D & 0xAA) != 0);
```

**Decoder:**

```
D = 1 << Q;
```

---

If you want a faster encoder,

```
byte QTable[]= {
  0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
  4, 4, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7
};

Q= QTable[D];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I already know about the bitwise operators, but is this way efficient enough to achieve the note I added to the end of the post?

Comment: @MuhammadNihad: mh, feel free to improve the decoder.

Answer (score 2):

> it can be done with bitwise operators but I need a really really fast and efficient

Since your input is pretty limited, i.e. 8 bits, I would go for a look-up table. The table can be based on a vector (or a simple array).

```
const uint8_t illegal_value = 0xff;
std::vector<uint8_t> encoder_table(256, illegal_value);
encoder_table[1] = 0;
encoder_table[2] = 1;
encoder_table[4] = 2;
encoder_table[8] = 3;
encoder_table[16] = 4;
encoder_table[32] = 5;
encoder_table[64] = 6;
encoder_table[128] = 7;

// Encode:
uint8_t D = a_one_hot_value;
uint8_t Q = encoder_table[D];
```

The relevant parts of the table is likely to stay in the level 1 cache all the time so performance should be quite good.

For decoding I will expect a simple bit shift to be the most efficient solution

```
// Decode:
uint8_t D = 1 << Q;
```

but a table can be tried for comparison. That table will only require 8 entries. Again something small that can be in level 1 cache.

Comment: Why a vector, rather than a `std::array`?  I think the latter could be made `constexpr`, FTW.